# Is there a CSS :visible (scroll) selector?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the style of visible elements using CSS only. Is there a selector that does it? It needs to work with Chrome and Firefox only. (I am building an extension / addon)

If there isn't, is there a way to change the style of visible elements with a light javascript?

---

**Visible within the current scroll position**. An element can be out of the scroll vision, or partially visible.

Comment: Why would you need to style the visible items only?  Styling invisible elements doesn't do anything anyway

Comment: If you're willing to use jQuery, it has a `:visible` pseudo-selector.

Comment: Like Kirean said, changing invisible elements does nothing, at least which is seen.  We assume you already have some JS or PHP which swaps out the in/visible elements as needed so why are you trying to avoid JS?  A little more clarity on what you are trying to achieve, and possibly some actual code as to what you have tried, we can provide better solutions.

Comment: It is worth noting here, that display:none and visibility:hidden are both invisible to the user but have vastly different meanings.  Keep this in mind to when considering the meaning of 'invisible' and 'visible'

Comment: You should note the difference in display:none and visibility:hidden. Invisible object may consume space …

Comment: @ShivanRaptor perhaps their business case doesn't include IE.  if that's the case, I want their business case!  But generally I agree, a solution isn't a solution unless it works everywhere.

Comment: And what kind of style you want to assign to invisible elements? ))) I mean there are some cases in javascript when we need this - but in pure CSS?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor if you are developing an addon for Firefox does your statement still matters?

Comment: @BrunoLM Yes, if it is the case, you really don't need to take care of other browsers. I would suggest you to state this in questions too, so that people can answer more accurately.

Comment: @ThomasJones It does something when hidden elements interferes with nth-child count like odd and even.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard pure CSS rule for assessing visibility.

As others have said, jQuery (if you wanted to use jQuery) has both a [CSS selector extension](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) `:visible` and the ability to execute `.is(':visible')` on any given jQuery object to get the computed style on any given DOM element with `.css("display")` or `.css("visibility")`.

It's not particularly simple in plain javascript to determine if an object is visible because you have to get the computedStyle (to take into account all possible CSS rules that might be affecting the element) and you have to make sure no parent objects are hidden causing the child element to be hidden.  This is a function I have in my own personal library:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// JF.isVisible function
//
// Determines if the passed in object is visible (not visibility:hidden, not display: none 
// and all parents are visible too.
//
// Source: http://snipplr.com/view/7215/javascript-dom-element-visibility-checker/
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JF.isVisible = function(obj)
{
    var style;

    if (obj == document) return true;

    if (!obj) return false;
    if (!obj.parentNode) return false;
    if (obj.style) {
        if (obj.style.display == 'none') return false;
        if (obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') return false;
    }

    //Try the computed style in a standard way
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, "")
        if (style.display == 'none') return false;
        if (style.visibility == 'hidden') return false;
    } else {
        //Or get the computed style using IE's silly proprietary way
        style = obj.currentStyle;
        if (style) {
            if (style['display'] == 'none') return false;
            if (style['visibility'] == 'hidden') return false;
       }
    }

    return JF.isVisible(obj.parentNode);
};
```

Comment: @davide-cannizzo - I rejected your edit to this answer as although you are encouraged to submit an alternative solution as an answer (or comment on this one) it's not appropriate to edit an existing [esp. _Accepted_] answer to [this extent](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18413980).  See: [Should I edit an answer if it is incomplete?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302824/8112776)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Way to select invisible elements, using pure CSS

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

However, if you have a class name or other selector, using jquery you can do something like the following

```
jQuery(selector).each(function(){
    Var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.css('visibility')==='hidden')
       //set your style
})
```

Edit: after your edit, there is definitely no way of selecting what is within the viewport with CSS alone.  It is a context free language of sorts.

However, you can always fool around with an elements offset position with jquery and determine if it's within the current viewport(window.scrollposition or something similar).  This type of solution gets messy quickly, though.

Comment: As shown on other solutions, there is a much easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure CSS way of doing this. As Kirean's comment already said, why would you want to style visible elements only? Invisible elements won't show their styling anyway. If you don't want the invisible element to take up space (aka, laid out), you should use `display: none;`

If you REALLY want a selector to select the visible elements, you could do what Widor suggested and use jQuery. You could first use jQuery to first select the visible elements, add a class to them, then use CSS to select the elements by that class.

```
$('div:visible').addClass('visibleElement');


.visibleElement {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `:visible` selector to me:
http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

**EDIT**: Saw your `javascript` tag before your 'no CSS' caveat.

But this is a CSS selector of sorts.